# Galaxy Note 2 JellyBean update

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have a Galaxy Note 2 GT-N7100 running on Android 4.1.1 JellyBean. The 4.1.2 update has been released a while back, but I still am reluctant to upgrade. I have read over the Internet that it causes the battery to drain faster than normal. Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there was Issue with Battery drain but they had solved the issue and you can go for 4.1.2 and performance is good.

Comment: Yes its true and write know the issue is fixed so no need to worry u can update you version to 4.1.2.